# Error in booting. Only boots in recovery mode

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb

It gives errors like: platform device creation failed

My config:
CPU: Intel Core i5-7200U 2.5ghz-3.1ghz

GPU: Intel Hd 620
GPU2: AMD Radeon 530 (Not Working)

RAM: 12 GB (2133Mhz)

I am using it on a live USB

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to boot?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.01 LTS